# Translucent UITextField Through Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

How can I make a UITextField more translucent than the Navigation Bar?

Basically I want the resulting TextField to be similar to that of Safari's:

[image]

Comment: Have you looked into the `alpha` property?

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, but since the UITextField is positioned over the navigation bar, it sets the alpha relative to the navigation bar under it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve this by using UIVisualEffectView with blur and vibrancy, more on this here: [UIVisualEffectView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uivisualeffect)